# How to treat bullet points as whitespace characters in vim?

Tags: vim, text, indentation

When using the auto-format option with

```
set formatoptions=taw
```

in vim, paragraphs starting with a bullet character will be formated like this:

```
• This is an
item of a list.
```

How can I tell vim to treat the '•' in the beginning of the line as a whitespace character to get

```
• This is an
  item of a list.
```

?

Comment: See also [this](http://superuser.com/q/99138/107337) SuperUser question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `comments` option(`:set fo+=cq` required):

```
:set fo+=cq
:set com+=fb:•
```

You can also set `formatlistpat` option(`:set fo+=n` required):

```
:set fo+=n
:set flp=^\\s*•\\s*
```

<sub>*Note:* use `\\` to get `\`</sub>

Comment: The first option didn't work for me when editing a plain text file. However, the second solution seems more appropriate anyway. Please note that 'autoindent' has to be set additionally for this to work.